# how can i reword a question to make it appropriate or what SE would it be approriate on?

Tags: support

This was put on hold, was wondering if anyone had a suggested edit or SE that you make this work?

> I've been doing web based coding for a little over 4 years. I have reached a point where I'm feeling somewhat confident about my PHP and JS abilities. I've got 3 websites up and running and each serving a purpose, even if it's small. I would like to learn to dev ios apps and i'm starting at the beginning.
>
> I'm leaning towards using apples Swift language as it appears they are in it for the long haul. If i were to say learning JS, PHP, SQL and CSS were like learning French, German & Italian, after looking at some intro obj C stuff (& only been a couple days), it feels like I would be trying to learn russian: completely different, very daunting. Also, this swift code seems pretty new, with a pretty small stackoverflow community. A huge reason my websites are functioning is because of the resources on stackoverflow :-)
>
> Should I take a step back and learn something else first? Which direction would that step be? Do I really need to start at learning C? I've Or is this hurdle going to look a lot smaller after a closer look?

Comment: You're not looking for a Q&A site with this type of question. You need somewhere where you can _discuss_ this with other people. SE's not the place for that, but some chat rooms might help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Mat, appreciate it